# No, minSDk(API 14) > deviceSdk(API 1)

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-debugging

I have been given a device(**ZTE Qlux 4g**) by a client as a testing device for some app. I work on **Ubuntu 14.04**. This same phone will be distributed to 500 cab drivers, so I can't avoid testing on this phone.

[image]

I'm not getting this error on any other device(Nexus4, Nexus5, Moto E, Xperia Z). I obviously have developers option & USB debugging enabled. I installed the app by downloading the APK via email & it runs.

When I connect this device to my Ubuntu machine, logcat shows just this 1 line:

**01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: insufficient permissions for device**

Any help in any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sudo adb kill-server &&
 sudo adb start-server`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Already tried. Didn't work.

Comment: All the downvoters, can you care to tell what more information should I give??

Comment: #Pranav Mahajan .Be cool .I am here

Answer (score 1):

The ZTE Qlux 4g uses Android 4.4, i.e. API 20. So either the given device is not genuine or have some bug in the device itself or ubuntu is not compatible with the ZTE Qlux 4g. 
So what you can do is first, try this on any other OS like windows/ mac (if possible).
If the problem persists then ask the client to give another device of same model.

Comment: From windows OS if I go to Device Manager settings & update ADB interface & then deploy some app, it works. Does this give any hint??

Comment: Yes. It does. It is sad that you probably cannot use this device in ubuntu. As Ubuntu probably does not supporting the device.

Comment: @RivuChakraborty `As Ubuntu probably does not supporting the device` Means ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about this?? And will the app function on the device when downloaded from playstore after release??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Means that probably in Ubuntu OS the ADB is unable to get the device information for some reason..

Comment: @PranavMahajan  it is not an issue that app is not running. The problem is that the adb in Ubuntu cannot get the device.
There is nothing regarding playstore download or app run here.

Comment: @RivuChakraborty Good ,But in here it works fine .Strange case . Your logic should be perfect . `Sometimes` . +1

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this may be a problem with this particular device, not model.

Comment: @RivuChakraborty Indeed indeed

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : I gave some wrong info in the question when I wrote that sharing APK via email doesn't work & app crashes. Actually it does run fine. I just can't run it from my Ubuntu machine. Sorry about that. Does this change your reviews about this problem??

Comment: @PranavMahajan if my answer is appropiate for you then please accept.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message:

[image]

Solution was on the command prompt, restart the connection with the command “adb kill-server”. Then reconnect the device.

[image]

---

Some background information about the device I'm using. The device I'm using is a test box (not a phone) that connects to my Laptop (Android Studio) via a USB cable or Ethernet cable. In order for me to connect the device, I had to do this:

Android Box Setup. Do these things before proceeding to bottom steps:

1) Connect the Laptop running Android Studio to the Gateway via USB cable or Ethernet (RJ45) cable.

2) Connect the Gateway to the same WiFi network as the laptop.

---

How to use the USB port to debug:

1) Open Command Prompt

2) Go to wherever you stored adb.exe file
[image]

3) Type in “adb connect ”. For example “adb connect 192.168.1.84” or “adb connect 192.168.1.94”.

3a) The IP address of the Android device can be found in Settings -> About tablet -> Status ->IP Address

3b) If the IP address of the Box is something like 10.134.114.51, then make sure that the box is connected to the same WiFi network as the laptop.

If you’re in the adb.exe directory, other adb commands include:

1) adb devices= Finds all devices currently connected to your computer.

2) adb kill-server= Disconnects the devices

---

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04
Virtualbox 5.0.24
Android 4.4-r5
Android Studio 2.1.2

I was getting these errors:
**Emulator unknown emulator-5554 disconnected.**

***But I was able to connect to the android virtual machine in a shell outside of Android Studio.***

**To resolve this, in Android Studio I had to start the terminal (icon on the bottom left) and run the following:**

```
netstat -ln | grep 5555 ;# As expected adb server was alive.
adb connect <ANDROID_VIRTUAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDR>:5555
```

Then the Innotek GmbH Virtual (Android 4.4.4 API19) machine item showed up above the emulator-5554 disconnected. I selected it and the debugger was working.